# NPM always returns exit code = 0 (but yarn does not, correctly)

Tags: npm, gitlab-ci

I am having a typescript project that is build via tsc to check for compile errors.
package.json

```
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc",
    },
```

`npm run build` finds the problem but it always let the pipeline pass...even if it clearly shows npm err.
[image: Non failing npm example]

I tried it with `yarn run build` and it shows the correct status (failure and the pipeline breaks)
[image: Correct failing yarn example]

I am totally lost where to look. It seems like npm is returning exit code 0, even if it should not. Anybody an idea where to look? Seems like a config issue, but cannot figure it out.

Comment: PS: Not happening for 
`npm info using npm@9.5.1
npm info using node@v18.16.0`. So probably just a bug in node / npm :-(